# Layout with tabs with ad on bottom and a button above it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-relativelayout

I have created a layout with tabs

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_id"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

One of the tabs is

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_section"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/image"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that before the ad loads I can see the button all the way on the bottom. How would I make the layout for the tab to take up exactly the space available instead of the whole screen? Same way if I added a button and make it be on top, instead of appearing below the tabs, it appears all the way on the top.

EDIT: I would like to make it look like this image

[image: This is how I want layout to look like]

The button is part of tab content that is shown and the ad is part of the main layout. The problem is that whenever I set button to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` then I end up with it being on the bottom and hidden behind the ad.

Comment: Can you please show a reference image or layout, how exact you want. So, we can make changes in your XML accordingly

Comment: @ParthPatel I added an image to show what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the root of your main layout to vertical `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Now you have two children in `LinearLayout` i.e `CoordinatorLayout` and `AdView`.

Since you want `AdView` to lie below `CoordinatorLayout` and `CordinatorLayout` to occupy the rest of the space,

set the height of `CoordinatorLayout` as `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with `android:layout_weight="1"` and the issue should be fixed.

Also change the height of `AppBarLayout` and `TabLayout` to `match_parent`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_id">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is no need to change in the other layout. But I would recommend you use `LinearLayout` as the root layout instead of `RelativeLayout`

So here are the changes that I would recommend doing in your tab layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image_section"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Attaching images for better understanding:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks!!! The only thing, please have TabLayout height to be wrap_content instead of match_parent because it doesn't work otherwise

Comment: Oh alright, never tried TabLayout. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried setting `minHeight` in Your AdView?

Change your `Tab` layout to this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image_section"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center"/>

<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```